# Using emitted type as type parameter in Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, generics, reflection.emit

```
[Name("Admin")]
public class TestAdmin : TestUserBase<TestAdmin>
{
    public TestAdmin(Type webDriverType) : base(webDriverType)
    {
    }
}
```

Currently, I have a bunch of classes of this form that I'd like to create at runtime using Reflection.Emit. However, I'm running into an issue when I attempt to add the parent - since the TestAdmin class doesn't exist before runtime, I don't know how to create

```
TestUserBase<TestAdmin>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you having trouble specifically because the argument to the base generic class is *this* class?

Comment: I believe you have a chicken and egg problem... The C# compiler may be able do this because it's probably not using Reflection.Emit to generate the IL. I'm not sure if there is a solution to this problem...

Comment: Does make-generic-method accept the type-builder? Actually, though, I do seem to recall some thorny chicken/egg areas that il-emit struggles with. Lately I'm using IKVM-reflection which has the same api as reflection-emit but which fixes a lot of these areas

Comment: @MarcGravell Lee's code works for me, I think this isn't one of the problematic cases.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Yes, that's been my issue. I think Lee's code will work, but haven't had a chance to test it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the parent type using [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.setparent.aspx):

```
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("TestAdmin", TypeAttributes.Public);
tb.SetParent(typeof(TestUserBase<>).MakeGenericType(tb));

Type theType = tb.CreateType();
```

Answer (score 3):

OK. I haven't been able to test this thoroughly, but I think this is possible. Try something like this:

Assuming your generic base class is already defined (i.e., you're not generating `TestUserBase<T>`), you should be able to do something like this:

```
var emittedType = module.DefineType("TestAdmin", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);
var baseType = typeof(TestUserBase<>).MakeGenericType(type);
emittedType.SetParent(baseType);
```

Of course, if `TestUserBase<T>` is begin generated, you can use this same logic using `MakeGenericType` on the dynamic type `TestUserBase<T>`. The `SetParent` logic is the same.